# How can I management Java Session with Framework or without

Tags: java, rest, session, session-management

I have a simple personal project.
This project has a rest API and is modular.
It has user-service, it needs session management.
For Example session time out, include permission, all login definations and etc.
Could you write to your Best Session Management Framework or method?

I was search firebase but I don't find firebase with session management.
Anyway. I'm waiting for your messages.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Spring security

Comment: I know Spring security but I need a newer framework. thanks for the answer.